# Optional property vs non-optional property?

Tags: typescript

Say I wanted to create an array of type `CoolObject`. Which would be a better way to go about things if some of the objects have the property `format` and some do not?

```
// Approach 1
   export interface CoolObject {
     name: string;
     color: string;
     format? string;
    }
```

or

```
// Approach 2
    export interface CoolObject {
     name: string;
     color: string;
     format: string;
    }
```

In the second approach I could check whether the format property has value or not.

Comment: Approach 1 is just fine for your purpose then.

Comment: How do you expect the second one to work exactly?

Comment: @TamasHegedus Edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second version tells the compiler that the property will always be there so it's definitely not a good way to express that that is optional. The `?` is the way to express taht a property is optional:

```
export interface CoolObject {
 name: string;
 color: string;
 format? string;
}
```

If you have `striuctNullChecks` typescript will even force you to validate that the property is defined whenever you try to access it

Answer (score 0):

> If the property `format` is not present in all of the objects, use
>   the following :-

```
export interface CoolObject {
  name    : string;
  color   : string;
  format ?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the collegues said,

```
export interface CoolObject {
  name    : string;
  color   : string;
  format ?: string;
}
```

is the convenient way to go.

If it´s a very performance hungry application, i would go the extra mile with

```
export interface CoolObject {
      name    : string;
      color   : string;
      format  : string;
    }
```

and set `format = undefined` if it´s not used.

The reason is, that the Javascript Compiler optimizes for "equal structured Objects"
So the objects

```
{ 
  name: 'LALALA'
  color: 'blue
}

{ 
  name: 'James Blond'
  color: 'rose'
}
```

are structuraly equal

```
{ 
  name: 'LALALA'
  color: 'blue
}

{ 
  name: 'James Blond'
  color: 'rose'
  format: 'lowlevel'
}
```

are not.

BUT... We are talking about optimzation that is needed for VERY VERY few UseCases.
Therefore, i would stick with the `format ?: string`, because it´s QUITE easier to implement and to read.

warm regards

Comment: It will work only for `strictNullChecks: false`. With checks, `format` must be explicitly typed as `string | undefined`.